# Как получить позицию в QuerySet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть задача знать позицию элемента в `QuerySet`, которая зависит от `order_by`, по нескольким параметрам.

К примеру:

```
proposals = Proposal.objects.filter(job=job).order_by(
    '-user__reputation', 
    'discount', 
    'amount
)
```

И если изменится, скажем, `user__reputation`, то, соответственно, и измениться позиция в `QuerySet`.

Как я могу получить эту позицию?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
list(proposals.values_list('id', flat=True)).index(obj.id)
```

Comment: А мне нужно индексировать не по id.

Скорее всего, как мне кажется, подойдёт enumerate(QuerySet, start=1)

Comment: В данном случае Вы преобразуете QuerySet в list, и берете index объекта по его id. Index будет меняться в зависимости от order_by, естественно :)

Comment: Напрямую взять номер в выборке нет возможности. Если речь идёт об отображении пользователю, то лично я не изощрялся с преобразованиями в list, а заводил переменную итератор, и проходя по всем элементам queryset добавлял им номер. Потом в выводе отображалось.

Answer (score -1):

В итоге, использую `enumerate`.

Если делать так:

```
obj = enumerate(Proposal.objects.all(), 1)
```

то `print(obj)` возвращает `<enumerate at 0x7f515fd3bea0>`.

Если же итерировать:

```
for i in obj:
    print(i) 

(1, <Proposal: y2htnrizbum2z0mpynvovnhzijpwqbza25rvyizisgahladjhm>)
```

А сериализовать удобно так:

```
serializers.serialize("json", Proposal.objects.all())

[{'index': index, 'object': obj} for index, obj in enumerate(json.loads(new_proposals_json), 1)]
```